# getting undefined in my application but on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking the following code in my application:

```
$("#jqxgrid").on("cellclick", function (event) 
  {
   var value = event.args.value;
   console.log("Checking Value: "+value);
   let element = $('#panelContentjqxPanel:contains(' + value + ')');

   console.log("Checking Value of element: "+element[0]);
    if(element[0] !== undefined) {                      
    var array = element[0].innerText.split(" ");
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {               
        if(array[i] === value) {
                    array[i] = '<span style="color:red">' + value + '</span>';
                      }
                    } 
                    let backToString = array.join(' ');
                    $('#jqxPanel').jqxPanel('clearcontent');
                    $('#jqxPanel').jqxPanel('append', backToString);
                }
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b35q3gxv/6/) for running code.  When I checked the two console.log statements in the JSFiddle, I get the following result depending upon the cell I click:

```
 Checking Value: Myeloma
 Checking Value of element: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

However, if I use the exact same code in my application, I keep on getting `undefined` for the following statement:

`console.log("Checking Value of element: "+element[0]);`

like the following:

```
Checking Value : Myeloma
Checking Value of element: undefined
```

Is there any alternative approach I can use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: show us the html from your code, not the fiddle

Comment: @depperm HTML is in JSfiddle

Comment: if the code is the same it should do the exact same thing

Comment: If it works there but not in your application, it probably involves how you're loading the javascript.  jsFiddle throws your code into an `onload` function by default, which waits for your HTML to be loaded before trying to execute.  It could also be that you dynamically load the `#panelContentjqxPanel` in your code, but it's static here.  Either way, there's not much we can offer if the only code we can see doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Just looked at the code.  It's not statically loaded in the fiddle, but it is dependent on other javascript executing for your code to work.  Are there any errors in your browser console when you run it in your application?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I don't see any other errors. Just that `undefined` result is making me to think whether I should consider any other approach for the on click handler?

Comment: @John but the click handler is working.  If it weren't, you wouldn't even see the `undefined` message.  What's not working is `let element = $('#panelContentjqxPanel:contains(' + value + ')');`.  It's not finding the element by its value and, thus, returning undefined.